# Botframework findEntity() issue

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've encountered a strange problem. Originally I had this to get my entity and it works correctly.

`x = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'get_x');`

However, for some reason I can't seem to figure out why, it stopped working and I had to change it to adding an additional `intent` to get it to work again.

`x = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'get_x');`

I was changing one of my intents on LUIS when I think this started to happen. Then I immediately undo all the changes to that intent, however all my intents were somehow affected to that as I need to add another additional `intent` to my entities parameter of the `findEntity()` method.

Is there something that I changed that could have cause this?

Edit: Actually changing my LUIS intents shouldn't have affected it as I've another bot using the same LUIS model and it's still working correctly.

Edit2: My `args` returns me this:

```
{ action: '*:SomeIntent',
  intent:
   { score: 0.999846458,
     intent: 'SomeIntent',
     intents:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     entities: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  libraryName: '*' }
```

Originally I could just use `args.entities` to find my entity but now the format changed and I've to use `args.intent.entities` to find my entity.

I found examples where [this one](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/) uses `args.entities` while [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js#L35) uses `args.intent.entities`. I know this doesn't really affect me that much as I can just change my code but I'm curious to know why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the error message, the code snippet and the args object?

Comment: I've updated with the result and examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the initialization of your bots' LuisRecognizers and compared them to each other? They most likely have a slight difference in code, the [BotBuilder-Sample/Node/intelligence-LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js) example uses only the botbuilder's [LuisRecognizer](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.luisrecognizer.html) on [line 27](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js#L27).

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL); // Line 27
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

bot.dialog('SearchHotels', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        ...
        var cityEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intents.entities, 'builtin.geography.city');
```

If only using the LuisRecognizer, you will need to use `args.intent.entities` instead of `args.entities`.

If you use [IntentDialog](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/) with LuisRecognizer, the setup is different in that you pass in `var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(<model>)` to `new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })`. The object inside of IntentDialog is the only parameter it receives in its construction, and the optional property `recognizers` takes an array of [IIntentRecognizers](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iintentrecognizer.html) (which is implemented by the [LuisRecognizer](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.luisrecognizer.html)).

The code below is taken from the [Entity Recognition](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/#entity-recognition) section of the Intent Dialog docs (your first example):

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer('<your models url>');
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('AddTask', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        var task = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'TaskTitle');
        if (!task) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, "What would you like to call the task?");
        } else {
            next({ response: task.entity });
        }
    },
    ...
]);
```

`intents.matches()` will [pass the full details of the match](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentdialog.html#matches) to the first step in the waterfall or dialog after an intent is matched. However, it will parse down to the intent property/object, meaning instead of having to use `args.intent.entities` you only use `args.entities`.

#### Edit:

> Ah, that may have been it. For some reason I remember it working right after I changed it. Just wondering, are there any pros and cons between the two? Or just coding style that's different?

It's not necessarily a pros-and-cons item, but the difference between the two methods is that in the first method you'll only be able to incorporate a single Luis model. *(See below)*

```
var mySingleRecognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(<model>);
bot.recognizer(mySingleRecognizer);
```

However, if you use `IntentDialog({ recognizers: ... })` you'll be able to pass in an array of recognizers; for example multiple LUIS models...

```
var HotelRecognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(<HotelModel>);
var DogRecognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(<DogModel>);
```

Or even different types of recognizers...

```
var RegularRecognizer = new builder.RegExpRecognizer('Cats', /^cat$/i);
```

Into your IntentDialog:

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [HotelRecognizer, DogRecognizer, RegularRecognizer] });

intents.matches('GetDog', [...]);
intents.matches('SearchHotels', [...]);
intents.matches('Cats', [...]);
```

Comment: Ah, that may have been it. For some reason I remember it working right after I changed it. Just wondering, are there any pros and cons between the two? Or just coding style that's different?