# Problems with findEntity()

Tags: botframework

I am having a problem similar to [Botframework findEntity() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194594/botframework-findentity-issue).

I have created a node.js botframework app using the azure interface.  I am using the azure ide for development (to keep things simple).

The relevant code is:

```
// Main dialog with LUIS
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
/*
.matches('<yourIntent>')... See details at http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/guides/understanding-natural-language/
*/

.matches('Help',(session, args) => {
    var entities = args.entities;
    var itype = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'ItemTypes');

        session.send(args.entities[0]["entity"]);
        session.send(args.entities[0]["type"]);

    session.send('How may I assist you? ' + JSON.stringify(args));
     session.send('Value of entity (didnt match) you said: \'%s\'.', itype);

})
```

the findEntity function returns null in itype (at least that is what I see in the session.send results.
I tried using both *args.entities* and *args.intents.entities*, no change.
When I look at the results of the args.entities[0]["entity"] and [type] I do get values.  The results of the JSON.stringify are below (also showing it is finding the entity).

> How may I assist you?
>   {"score":0.970185757,"intent":"Help","intents":[{"intent":"Help","score":0.970185757},{"intent":"Joke","score":0.0711096451},{"intent":"Greeting","score":0.0438234434},{"intent":"None","score":0.0408537947},{"intent":"Goodbye","score":0.04074517}],"entities":[{"entity":"stapler","type":"ItemTypes","

I'm assuming there is more but that it was cut off by the chat window.

I'm new to every technology involved and will take any help I can get.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using currently?

Comment: Your code looks fine, except you need to add at least a `session.endDialog()` to the end of this dialog so your chatbot doesn't get stuck in said dialog.

Comment: Another thing to note is that `findEntity()` returns the entire entity object, not just the `"entity"` value of what you're looking for. Your final `session.send()` as it is should end in something like `'[object Object]'.` Not `'stapler'.`

Comment: Since the findEntity returns the entire object, I ended up having to use (in the last line of code) itype.entity to retrieve the stapler.